# 2.93 How to compare active view layer in shader editor with driver?

Tags: python, shaders, drivers

I need to update shader settings for the environment according to the active view layer.
I would like to just have a Value node that checks if the active view layer is a specific view layer. Something like,

```
bpy.context.view_layer == "specific layer"
bpy.context.window.view_layer == "specific layer"
bpy.context.view_layer.name == "specific layer"
```

(etc.)
But every variation of this I have tried fails to process. Can what I am trying to do be done? How?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new driver to the value node and set this as the expression: `depsgraph.view_layer.name == "YourViewLayerName"`